# making something like lag work with group_by

Tags: r

Tried to reproduce my pipeline with simplified data/code as follows:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
    date = c(
        as.Date("2015-1-1")
        , as.Date("2015-2-1")
        , as.Date("2015-3-1")
        , as.Date("2015-4-1")
        , as.Date("2015-5-1")
        , as.Date("2015-6-1")

        , as.Date("2015-1-1")
        , as.Date("2015-2-1")
        , as.Date("2015-3-1")
        , as.Date("2015-4-1")
        , as.Date("2015-5-1")
        , as.Date("2015-6-1")

    )
    ,value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6 ,7,8,9,10,11,12)
    ,category = as.factor(c("cat1","cat1","cat1","cat1","cat1","cat1"  ,"cat2","cat2","cat2","cat2","cat2","cat2"))
) %>%
group_by(
    date = floor_date(date, unit = "monthly")
    ,category 
) %>%
summarise(
    value = min(value)
) %>%
mutate(
    month_minus_1 = lag(value, n=1)
    , month_minus_2 = lag(value, n=2)
) %>%
arrange(
    category 
    , value
)
df
```

I added floor_date to indicate that I will rollup some figures by month and use some statistic (here min). Anyway, how can I apply lag to each group as the results the above produces are wrong:

```
date category value month_minus_1 month_minus_2
2015-01-01  cat1    1   NA  NA
2015-02-01  cat1    2   NA  NA
2015-03-01  cat1    3   NA  NA
2015-04-01  cat1    4   NA  NA
2015-05-01  cat1    5   NA  NA
2015-06-01  cat1    6   NA  NA
2015-01-01  cat2    7   1   NA
2015-02-01  cat2    8   2   NA
2015-03-01  cat2    9   3   NA
2015-04-01  cat2    10  4   NA
2015-05-01  cat2    11  5   NA
2015-06-01  cat2    12  6   NA
```

Expected output:

```
 date category value month_minus_1 month_minus_2
    2015-01-01  cat1    1   NA  NA
    2015-02-01  cat1    2   1   NA
    2015-03-01  cat1    3   2   1
    2015-04-01  cat1    4   3   2
    2015-05-01  cat1    5   4   3
    2015-06-01  cat1    6   5   4
    2015-01-01  cat2    7   NA  NA
    2015-02-01  cat2    8   7   NA
    2015-03-01  cat2    9   8   7
    2015-04-01  cat2    10  9   8
    2015-05-01  cat2    11  10  9
    2015-06-01  cat2    12  11  10
```

Comment: Please provide your expected output.

Comment: @DarrenTsai - sorry thought that was obvious ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that `date` should not be inside `dplyr::group_by()`.

`dplyr::group_by()` creates separate mini-data.frames that functions like `dplyr::lag()` can't see outside of.  So essentially you were creating twelve data.frames with a single row.

```r
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c(
    "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-06-01", 
    "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-06-01" 
  )),
  value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6 ,7,8,9,10,11,12),
  category = as.factor(c("cat1","cat1","cat1","cat1","cat1","cat1"  ,"cat2","cat2","cat2","cat2","cat2","cat2"))
) %>% 
group_by(category) %>%
mutate(
  month_minus_1 = lag(value, n=1, order_by = date),
  month_minus_2 = lag(value, n=2, order_by = date)
) %>%
ungroup()
```

Results:

```r
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   date       value category month_minus_1 month_minus_2
   <date>     <dbl> <fct>            <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 2015-01-01     1 cat1                NA            NA
 2 2015-02-01     2 cat1                 1            NA
 3 2015-03-01     3 cat1                 2             1
 4 2015-04-01     4 cat1                 3             2
 5 2015-05-01     5 cat1                 4             3
 6 2015-06-01     6 cat1                 5             4
 7 2015-01-01     7 cat2                NA            NA
 8 2015-02-01     8 cat2                 7            NA
 9 2015-03-01     9 cat2                 8             7
10 2015-04-01    10 cat2                 9             8
11 2015-05-01    11 cat2                10             9
12 2015-06-01    12 cat2                11            10
```

I see that you want to summarize something in your real scenario (not the simplified scenario you present here).  I'd do something like this, where the floor and stat are calculated before subsetting for the lag.  That first `dplyr::ungroup()` isn't required, but I like how it communicates the intent better.

```r
data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c(
    "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-06-01", 
    "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-06-01" 
  )),
  value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6 ,7,8,9,10,11,12),
  category = as.factor(c("cat1","cat1","cat1","cat1","cat1","cat1"  ,"cat2","cat2","cat2","cat2","cat2","cat2"))
) %>%
dplyr::mutate(
  month_floor = floor_date(date, unit = "monthly")
) %>%
group_by(category, month_floor) %>%
summarize(
  value_mean   = mean(value) # Or the rollup statistic you're referring to.
) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
group_by(category) %>%
mutate(
  month_minus_1 = lag(value_mean, n=1, order_by = month_floor),
  month_minus_2 = lag(value_mean, n=2, order_by = month_floor)
) %>%
ungroup()
```

Comment: Amazing - I had a similar problem with rollmean + rollmedian

Answer (score 1):

`summarize` removes one 'layer' of grouping. So after summarize you have a df only grouped by `date` while you want a group by category.

Simply switching the two grouping vars gets you what you need:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(category,
           date = floor_date(date, unit = "monthly")
           ) %>%
  summarise(value = min(value)) %>%
  mutate(month_minus_1 = lag(value, n = 1),
         month_minus_2 = lag(value, n = 2)) %>%
  arrange(category,
          value)

#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#> # Groups:   category [2]
#>    category date       value month_minus_1 month_minus_2
#>    <fct>    <date>     <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 cat1     2015-01-01     1            NA            NA
#>  2 cat1     2015-02-01     2             1            NA
#>  3 cat1     2015-03-01     3             2             1
#>  4 cat1     2015-04-01     4             3             2
#>  5 cat1     2015-05-01     5             4             3
#>  6 cat1     2015-06-01     6             5             4
#>  7 cat2     2015-01-01     7            NA            NA
#>  8 cat2     2015-02-01     8             7            NA
#>  9 cat2     2015-03-01     9             8             7
#> 10 cat2     2015-04-01    10             9             8
#> 11 cat2     2015-05-01    11            10             9
#> 12 cat2     2015-06-01    12            11            10
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks. This works. I did not know that the order matters at all! I am not sure if I can accept your first answer - see what wibeasley says below ...

Comment: This is exactly the same, maybe less explicit, but I think clearer. It does take into account any summarizing you want to do

Comment: Thanks fair enough. However, this did not work when applied to rollmean + rollmedian. I know this is not the question. However, the explicit approach works. So not sure if what you say is generalisable?